# Separate Domain Registrar and Host, possible to use CDN?

Tags: cdn, nameservers

I am just wondering if this is possible/how I could go about doing this.

I work for a company that has their domain name registered on `Site A` while their hosting is on `Site B`. This is no issue as we just have the Registrar at `Site A` point the Name Servers to `Site B`. Easy.

Where I get a little confused, is say I would like to use a CDN such as CloudFlare (`Site C`), typically in a basic case, I would go to the registrar/host and just change my Name Servers to the ones given by CloudFlare. However if my Registrar and Domain Host are different, it appears someone could get lost in the mix, as if I go from `Site A` point to `Site C` .. how does host at `Site B` supply `Site C` with all the information to host and control the CDN for?

Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to CloudFlare and got this very simple, perfect answer.

> Here's how it will work for you :
>
> At your domain registrar, you will set your authoritative name servers to the ones that CloudFlare will assign to you when you sign up.
>
> Within CloudFlare, using our dashboard, you will configure your DNS zone file to point your domain to the IP address of the server assigned to you by your hosting provider.
>
> The CloudFlare reverse proxy does the rest!

Hope this helps!