# Can I direct a cpanel folder to a domain name hosted with a different registrar?

Tags: cpanel, registrar

I'm wondering if this is possible and I'm not sure that it is. Before I explain, I found one other post [here]: [Separate Domain Registrar and Host, possible to use CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518681/separate-domain-registrar-and-host-possible-to-use-cdn) which sounds similar to my problem, but I specifically don't want to point the Name Servers away. I only mention this because my question is going to sound very similar.

So I'm trying to help a friend who has a Domain Name registered on Site A (let's assume it's a place like Wix). He also has a hosting package on Site B (to have cpanel access for a site he had built with HTML & PHP).

for example:
1. www.yourdomain.com is hosted on Wix with a template website
2. "database" is a cpanel folder on Site B

Is there a way to have www.yourdomain.com/database link to the "database" folder on Site B's hosting -- without changing the Name Servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe you can point a directory to a completely different server or hosting package.

However creating a sub domain instead could be your answer.

Is there anything stopping you from using database.yourdomain.com and creating an A record for this in your domain registrar and point it to the hosting package of database?

Comment: Thank you, Lee! That was my assumption too, that it can't be done directly. Good question on subdomain. I'll have to look into that option. If they allow subdomains - is it as easy as pointing the Name Servers of the subdomain to the hosting package? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Nothing to do with name servers. You just add a new A record in your domain control panel to point the sub domain to the IP address of the web server the other hosting package is using. Ask your domain registrar and the support of th second web host and they’ll help you in more detail.